# where is Chinese tokenizer in SQLite FTS3?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, android-sqlite, fts3

I am working on SQLite-FTS3 for multi-langugage searching.

It seems there is not tokenizer for Chinese or Korean.

How can I search using Chinese and Korean language in FTS3?

Answer (score 0):

In Android, it is not possible to add user-defined tokenizers.

So you have to live with the restrictions of the built-in tokenizer (any sequence of glyphs without space characters is treated as a single term).

Comment: I do not know whether i can get it by using Android-NDK to add custom C code that implementing ntf3 tokenizer interface ?

maybe it can't work for me if use built-in tokenizer with chinese and other non-English language.how to resolve it ? using lucene? or?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the NDK to access your own copy of SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with FTS5 + External Content + Generated column + JiebaAnalysis.

You can add JiebaAnalysis as a custom function to Triggers.